# Update tpl file

Tags: prestashop

I have updated a tpl file but I cann't see the change on my browser

```
{if $logged}
<div class="header_user_info">
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" title="{l s='View my customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="account" rel="nofollow"><span>{$cookie->customer_firstname} {$cookie->customer_lastname}</span></a>
</div>
{/if}
<div class="header_user_info">
    {if $logged}
        <a class="logout" href="{$link->getPageLink('index', true, NULL, "mylogout")|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log me out' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign out' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
    {else}
        <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
        <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
    {/if}

</div>
```

This code is called in my header.tpl with

```
{hook h="displayNav"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the next route to compile all files in the theme

Advanced Parameters -> Performance -> Compile always